# How to trigger another Touchable component's press event by tap a touchable component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How to trigger another Touchable component's press event by tap a touchable component? thanks!

Example:-

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={this._triggerSecond}>
  <Image
    style={styles.button}
    source={require('./myButton.png')}
  />
</TouchableHighlight>
```

If user will tap on first TouchableHighlight then it should trigger second TouchableHighlight.

```
<TouchableHighlight>
  <Image
    style={styles.button}
    source={require('./myButton.png')}
  />
</TouchableHighlight>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I guess instead of thinking in that way I guess you can thinking this as just another `TouchableHighlight` calling the same method such as:

```
// First one 
<TouchableHighlight onPress={this._method}>
  <Image
    style={styles.button}
    source={require('./myButton.png')}
  />
</TouchableHighlight>

// Second one
<TouchableHighlight onPress={this._method}>
  <Image
    style={styles.button}
    source={require('./myButton.png')}
  />
</TouchableHighlight>
```

In this way both components when tap are going to invoke to the same `method`.

Comment: Thank you. but i just want to know, how to programmatically trigger the touch event in react native.

Comment: First touchable will trigger one function as well as trigger second touchable component. which will trigger another function.

Comment: I see AFAIK there's no method from `TouchableHighlight` to invoke it like a `click()` on the web but I guess you can put that logic into methods of the same class. after `method1` is called you can call `method2` from there.

Comment: Thank you mitogh.

Comment: This really seems to be the only way. Using a ref from one touchable component to trigger it via another does not seem to work. The ref is there but it does not expose anything useful. There is no `ref.current`, no `ref.onPress`, no `ref.current.onPress`, no `ref.props` whatsoever. It might work for a Button component (there are SO answers explaining this), but the refs from Touchable_ components seem to be just View instances.

Answer (score 7):

For those who still need to fire a press programmatically, I found a solution. First you need to bind your touchable to `this` by using ref :

```js
<TouchableOpacity
  onPress={() => alert("click")}
  ref={(touchable) => this._touchable = touchable}
>
```

then when you want to launch onPress without clicking it just call

```js
this._touchable.touchableHandlePress()
```

Comment: When I am executing this line it says this._touchable.touchableHandlePress() is no a function.

Comment: Not working for react-native 0.64, probably the same issue with later versions as well.