# Handle formik form outside of formik component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a `formik` form as follow. I am able to submit the form inside formik component. But how could i submit it outside of formik component (inside footer button for this example).

Formik url: [Click here](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/guides/react-native)

Particulary, how could i access this values `handleChange, values, handleSubmit, errors,isValid,touched, handleBlur, isSubmitting,` outside of `Formik` component.

I am doing it in `react-native` but i guess concept of react would help, particularly with the usage of `useRef` etc. Found few examples online using ref but none of it work.

```
<View>
    <Formik
        onSubmit={async values => {
            this.handleSubmit(values);
            await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
            console.warn(values);
        }}
        validationSchema={validationSchema}>
        {({
        handleChange,
        values,
        handleSubmit,
        errors,
        isValid,
        touched,
        handleBlur,
        isSubmitting,
        }) => (
        <View>
            <Form>
                <Text>First Name</Text>
                <TextInput
                    name="first_name"
                    value={values.first_name}
                    onChangeText={handleChange('first_name')}
                />
                {errors.first_name ? (
                <Text>{errors.first_name}</Text>/>
                ) : (
                    <></>
                )}
                <Button onPress={handleSubmit}>
                    <Text>Submit</Text>
                </Button>
            </Form>
        </View>
        )}
    </Formik>
    <Footer>
        <Button>Submit</Button>
    </Footer>
</View>
```

Comment: Why not just include the `<Footer />` inside the `<Formik />`?

Comment: @Rawrplus thats because the footer component should reside on the bottom of the form and stay in absolute position. Whereas the form part is scrollable (the form actually has 10+ input field). So thats not making sense of putting footer inside the form. And this is just example of one scenario. The form submission button could be reside in header/footer or anywhere. The core of this is to have form submission outside of formik component. Hope that make sense to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue when creating a reusable popup and having the save button in the popup template and the formik form in the popup content (so I was unable to put the button inside the form since the footer was reused in any popup).

I solved it by adding a ref to the submit button in the form and hiding the button with css and then triggering a click on the hidden submit button pragmatically when clicking on the desired submit button.

Maybe not the cleanest solution but it worked for me.

Here is a basic sample

```
<Formik>
    ....
    <Field>
    <Field>
    ...
    <button type="submit" style={{display:"none"}}  ref={this.submitButton}/> 
</Formik>

<div className="ftr">
    <button onClick={() => this.submitButton.current.click()}>Save</button>
</div>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Unfortunately i am using react native. Your solution of using a html and javascript programmitically click does not work.

Comment: @vincentsty Sorry I didn't see you `react-native` tag, I don't have taht much experience with react native but I believe you can do the same in react native, see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43369260/how-to-trigger-another-touchable-components-press-event-by-tap-a-touchable-comp

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of how to access the formik props outside of the Formik component